# Explaination of this "global" if statement that shows up in multiple files?

Tags: c#

I am trying to figure out how to disable this IF statement so the code doesn't run unfortuanately I dont know what this IF statement is called so Im having trouble googling it.[image: the if statement]

I have tried searching for solutions online and looking in files.

Comment: It's [Conditional compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives#conditional-compilation)

Answer (score 1):

That's a C# [conditional compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives) directive.

If you right-click on your project in Solution Explorer and go to Build > General > Conditional compilation symbols, you'll see the 'symbols' that are set and can be used in those `#if` statements. Typically you configure different symbols depending on the type of build you're running.